# Show that every norm is a $1$-lipschitz function

Tags: calculus, general-topology, normed-spaces

> Let $\|\cdot\|_0$, a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the function $\|\cdot\|_0$ is $1$-lipschitz and hence, continuous.

Meaning, I need to prove that: $$\big|\|x\|_0-\|y\|_0\big| \le \|x-y\|$$

Now, I'm familiar with the reverse triangle inequality proof which will results: $$\big|\|x\|_0-\|y\|_0\big| \le \|x-y\|_0$$

but please notice that the $\|x-y\|$ should be the **euclidean norm.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is meant to be 1-Lipschitz with respect to $\| \cdot \|_0$. Otherwise the claim would be false, consider for example the norm $\| \cdot \|_0 := 2 \| \cdot \|$ for $y = 0$ and an arbitrary $x \ne 0$.

Comment: Oh thank you. I probably got it wrong then.

Comment: @Elimination I think it can be useful to check the exact definition of a $1$-Lipschitz function. Let $(E,d_{E})$ and $(F,d_{F})$ be two metric spaces. A function $\varphi:E\to F$ is $k$-Lipschitz (where $k>0$ is a positive real number) if for any $x,y\in E$, we have $$d_{F}\big(\varphi(x)\,,\,\varphi(y)\big)\le k\cdot d_{E}(x,y)$$ As the norm is (here) an application from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{+}$, we get what Dominik said.